# Android - Native crash at /system/lib/libRScpp.so

Tags: android

I've just published my app onto google play... and the first person to download it was my brother... but the app crashes immediately on his Samsang Galaxy Tab S. The app works on the emulator (tried both ARM and x86) and no problems on my test devices at home (HTC M8, HTC desire, and ASUS Nexus 7 2012 and 2013).

Anway... the error report comes back;

"Native crash at /system/lib/libRScpp.so"

What does this mean? and how do I investigate further? My app certainly has native functions - but not in the splash screen and menu activities (where it crashes on my brother's device).

There is a "stack trace" as follows...

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/chagallwifixx/chagallwifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/T800XXU1ANFB:user/release-keys'
Revision: '7'
pid: 7819, tid: 7819, name: et.pokerprophet >>> darwi.net.pokerprophet <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000028
r0 beec3d0c r1 00000000 r2 42200000 r3 00000002
r4 beec3d0c r5 beec3d44 r6 beec3d9c r7 7aac69c8
r8 00000132 r9 00000780 sl 7bcef020 fp 00000014
ip 40ceec50 sp beec3d00 lr 415d071f pc 415ce9c2 cpsr 600f0030
d0 646e756f62206c65 d1 7869702035322d30
d2 7665727020796229 d3 7272652073756f3a
d4 0000000000000000 d5 0000000000100000
d6 0000000000100000 d7 4220000041c80000
d8 0000001400000106 d9 4491200043ae8000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 0000000000100000 d19 0000000000000000
d20 000000000003fb10 d21 ff0000000000003f
d22 000000000003fb00 d23 0000000000000001
d24 00000000000002b8 d25 0000000000000001
d26 000000007ba91b80 d27 000000007ba91b81
d28 0000000000000000 d29 0000000000000000
d30 0000000000000000 d31 0000000000000000
scr 20000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 0000b9c2 /system/lib/libRScpp.so
#01 pc 0000d71b /system/lib/libRScpp.so (android::RSC::ScriptIntrinsicBlur::setInput(android::RSC::sp<android::RSC::Allocation>)+10)
#02 pc 00011a29 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#03 pc 00011c15 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#04 pc 0002cf15 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#05 pc 0002057b /system/lib/libhwui.so
#06 pc 000221d7 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#07 pc 00017fbd /system/lib/libhwui.so
#08 pc 0001568d /system/lib/libhwui.so
#09 pc 000154ff /system/lib/libhwui.so
#10 pc 0001e27f /system/lib/libhwui.so
#11 pc 0006c94d /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#12 pc 0001eb0c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#13 pc 0004f08b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#14 pc 00027f20 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#15 pc 0002ef54 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#16 pc 0002c5b8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#17 pc 0006176d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
#18 pc 00069b0f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#19 pc 00027f20 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#20 pc 0002ef54 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#21 pc 0002c5b8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#22 pc 00061489 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#23 pc 0004ac73 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#24 pc 0005251b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#25 pc 00053aaf /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
#26 pc 0000105b /system/bin/app_process
#27 pc 0000e45f /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
#28 pc 00000d7c /system/bin/app_process

code around pc:
415ce9a0 bd104620 000075e0 ffffffd8 4604b510 
415ce9b0 ffeaf7ff f7fb4620 4620ea12 b510bd10 
415ce9c0 6a884604 b1106020 f7fc3004 4620fe69 
415ce9d0 0000bd10 1a90ee07 4603b507 eef59101 
415ce9e0 eef17ac0 dd0cfa10 7a09eeb3 7ac7eef4 
415ce9f0 fa10eef1 2100d805 2304aa01 fe4af7ff 
415cea00 4a03e005 68d82101 f7fc447a bd0efa9f 
415cea10 00005077 2310460a f7ff2101 460abe3b 
415cea20 21002340 be36f7ff 4a00eeb7 ed9fb500 
415cea30 edd11a1d b0917a00 0a01ed91 0a02edd1 
415cea40 7a03ed91 1a04edd1 2a05ed91 2a06edd1 
415cea50 3a07ed91 3a08edd1 edcd4669 ed8d7a00 
415cea60 edcd0a01 ed8d0a02 ed8d1a03 edcd7a04 
415cea70 ed8d1a05 ed8d2a06 edcd1a07 ed8d2a08 
415cea80 edcd3a09 ed8d3a0a ed8d1a0b ed8d1a0c 
415cea90 ed8d1a0d ed8d1a0e f7ff4a0f b011ffc0 

code around lr:
415d06fc aa032101 ffa2f7fd f7faa803 bd7ffd03 
415d070c 00003418 4604b57f a801460d f7fe6809 
415d071c a802f950 f7fd9901 9e02fa78 0128f104 
415d072c f7fba803 a903f90d f7fb4630 4606f8bd 
415d073c f7faa803 a802fce7 fce4f7fa f7faa801 
415d074c b936fce1 21034a09 447a68e0 fbf8f7fa 
415d075c 4629e00b f7fba803 4620f8f3 aa032101 
415d076c ff6cf7fd f7faa803 bd7ffccd 000034e2 
415d077c 4604b57f a801460d f7fe6809 a802f91a 
415d078c f7fd9901 9e02fa42 0128f104 f7fba803 
415d079c a903f8d7 f7fb4630 4606f887 f7faa803 
415d07ac a802fcb1 fcaef7fa 4a0fb926 68e02103 
415d07bc e006447a 6b189b01 4a0cb930 68e02101 
415d07cc f7fa447a e00bfbbd a8034629 f8b8f7fb 
415d07dc 21004620 f7fdaa03 a803ff31 fc92f7fa 
415d07ec f7faa801 bd7ffc8f 0000349a 000034a8
```

I am probably way out of my depth here... what is the best way for a noob to approach this?

Comment: It's crashing in RenderScript intrinsic code which had been called from native code. Did you setup the blur intrinsic in your app properly?

Comment: What is RenderScript? I don't even know what it is... let alone called it. Or intrinsic blurs. My native codes take a string from java score it as a poker hand and then returns a string back to java!

Comment: Ok... just googled RenderScript. I haven't gone anywhere near this in my code. Could it be called without my knowledge by any other more benign calls?

Comment: Interesting. But, it's difficult to say what could be happening without seeing code. The framework does use RS for certain font rendering ops, but that shouldn't really cone into play here. Unfortunately, without a real device for you to test and debug with, it is going to be difficult. Can you add more logging to your app and have your brother install the new version and test?

Answer (score 2):

This bug report mentions disabling font shadows. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72068

From the ticket:

> If I remove:
>
> ```
>     android:shadowColor="@color/brown_light" 
>     android:shadowRadius="30"
> ```
>
> The problem disappears.

Comment: This ended up being the issue for me. There's currently a max shadowRadius of 25... just crashes... very cool.