# ScriptIntrinsicBlur crashes on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, renderscript

Using build tools 25.0.3 and renderscriptTargetApi 21, `Allocation.createFromBitmap` for both input and output (2 bitmaps), basically everything quite like in the sample:

```
Allocation inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);
...
ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
blurScript.setRadius(blurRadius);
blurScript.setInput(inAllocation);
blurScript.forEach(outAllocation);
outAllocation.copyTo(outputBitmap);
```

Suddenly in recent days I started getting the following crash on Samsung Galaxy S6 devices:

```
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zenltexx/zenlte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G928FXXS2BPG2:user/release-keys'
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: Revision: '9'
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: pid: 14905, tid: 14985, name: RenderThread  >>> my.app <<<
05-10 12:11:48.751 ? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x28
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f5a13ef50  x1   0000007f8403e588  x2   9592f52992562749  x3   9592f52992562749
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x4   ffffffffffffffff  x5   8080808000000000  x6   0000000080808080  x7   fefefeff636d746e
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   fefefefefefefeff  x10  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f  x11  0101010101010101
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000020  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000001  x15  0000000000000006
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fa3a84b08  x17  0000007fa3018b3c  x18  0000007fa57a7720  x19  0000007f561975d8
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f8403e588  x21  0000007f7e3ef000  x22  0000007f56b8d408  x23  0000000000000002
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007f8403e648  x25  0000007f8403e588  x26  0000007f54ef2000  x27  0000000000000002
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f561975d8  x29  0000007f8403e4e0  x30  0000007fa3a0e14c
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f8403e4a0  pc   0000007fa3018b5c  pstate 0000000060000000
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001bb5c  /system/lib64/libRScpp.so (_ZN7android3RSC19ScriptIntrinsicBlur8setInputENS0_2spINS0_10AllocationEEE+32)
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000004a148  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000004a8b4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000083ac4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000005f1c0  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000000000005ff74  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000000000003d0a4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000039780  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000003a198  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000058420  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000283bc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000002aa68  /system/lib64/libhwui.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000002ef50  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+124)
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000000000001699c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208)
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000000000095160  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96)
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00000000000161ec  /system/lib64/libutils.so
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 0000000000065f20  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
05-10 12:11:48.791 ? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 000000000001edec  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

This crash seems not to happen anywhere else, so far. Has anyone hit the same issue and know any cause or workaround for it?

Comment: You sure your inAllocation is not null?

Comment: From `Allocation.createFromBitmap`: `return new Allocation(id, rs, t, true, usage, mips);` - as the variable is not changed since createFromBitmap, I can't see how it could be null, but I'll check it in the problem device as well

Comment: Seems to be similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580179/android-native-crash-at-system-lib-librscpp-so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this was caused by a large text shadow that was displayed at the same time, instead of my own RenderScript call. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580179/android-native-crash-at-system-lib-librscpp-so) for details.